# Google Sheet Script - Import unique values from multiple spreadsheets with the same name

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've currently got a VLOOKUP & IMPORTRANGE in my 'UNIQUE SKUS' sheet linked to multiple 'PURCHASES' sheet from different month folders that's inside a year folder, this imports unique SKU data, also pulling the name and price associated with that.

I'm looking to create script which can search through every spreadsheet named 'PUCHASES' to then import the unique range into my 'UNIQUE SKUS' so when I create new files I don't have to keep adjusting the formula.

Folder Tree Example:

```
ROOT
  YEAR
    MONTH
      'PURACHSES' (out of)
      'EXPENSES'
    MONTH
      'PURACHSES' (out of)
      'EXPENSES'
  YEAR
    MONTH
      'PURACHSES' (out of)
      'EXPENSES'
    MONTH
      'PURACHSES' (out of)
      'EXPENSES'
  DATABASE
    'UNIQUE SKUS' (into)
```

I'm struggling to find anything similar to this online so having issues getting a base script made

Any help me it would be much appreciated!
Apologies if this is badly explained

Comment: So what is your seearch criteria and what do  purchases look like? A real easy way to find you purchases folders is to keep a list of their id's in a spreadsheet

Comment: Would I be able to get a list of all spreadsheets in my drive, and print out the id of spreadsheets with a specific name? or would it be better to just manually list all IDs and put into a hidden sheet to then grab from?

Comment: I was suggesting that rather than do a recursive function to walk it's way through a directory structure, it would be faster for you to have a build a list of id's that you want searched.  The answer the question can you get a list of spreadsheets in your drive is yes.